# Obtener medidas de pantalla en las unidades correctas para crear en OpenCV un área de captura del tamaño de toda la pantalla del monitor

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, opencv, winapi

Estoy intentando crear un capturador de pantalla que capture toda la pantalla del pc, pero como quiero que se adapte a diferentes ordenadores (osea diferentes pantallas con diferentes medidas) buscaba que el ajuste del area de captura sea automatico.

Utilice el siguiente codigo, usando la librería de windows `win32api` que por medio de su funcion `GetSystemMetrics`, pude obtener estas 2 medidas de la pantalla: `GetSystemMetrics(0)` correspondiente al ancho y `GetSystemMetrics(1)` correspondiente al alto.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image

from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

print("Ancho de Pantalla =", GetSystemMetrics(0))
print("Alto de Pantalla =", GetSystemMetrics(1))

#Establezco las coordenadas de la pantalla que quiero capturar
#mon = {'left': 160, 'top': 160, 'width': 700, 'height': 700} #Ajuste manual de area de captura
mon = {'left': 0, 'top': 0, 'width': GetSystemMetrics(0), 'height': GetSystemMetrics(1)}

with mss() as sct:
    #Bucle que mantiene activa la captura
    while True:
        screenShot = sct.grab(mon)
        img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (screenShot.width, screenShot.height), screenShot.rgb, )
        frame = np.array(img)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        cv2.imshow('window_name', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(33) & 0xFF in (ord('q'), 27, ):
            break
```

Para plantear el diccionario con el que se ajusta el area de captura (aunque en este caso lo que estoy buscando es conseguir que capture desde los 0 hacia las coordenadas maximas que permite la pantalla), utilice la convencion de coordenadas de OpenCV.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy en duda es porque las coordenadas que me devuelve al imprimir son:

```
Ancho de Pantalla = 1536
Alto de Pantalla = 864
```

Y sin embargo, el programa no logra abarcar toda mi pantalla, faltandole mas tanto en ancho como en alto. Lo que me tiene en dudas, es que si estoy bien informado, tanto `win32api` como `OpenCV` utilizan como unidad de medida de imagen el pixel (px), por lo que deberian coincidir las coordenadas maximas de la pantalla con las que captura opencv, aunque esto no ocurre.

Que conversiones o unidades deberia manejar para hacer esto?

Comment: Tal vez te funcione `pyautogui.size()` de la librería pyautogui

Comment: @nadie Funciona perfecto con esa librería, aunque no me explico porque con `win32api` falla.

Comment: Es posible que win32api coja las medidas sin contar con la barra de herramientas ni el menú de minimizar, minimizar tamaño y  cerrar

Comment: @nadie Es bastante probable aunque lo que falta seleccionar es casi 4 o 3 barras de menu de inicio. Y tambien tiene error en el ancho y no solo en el alto.  La medida correcta es `Ancho de Pantalla = 1920`  y  `Alto de Pantalla = 1080`, sin embargo `win32api` da  `Ancho de Pantalla = 1536` y `Alto de Pantalla = 864`, en verdad es bastante diferencia `384` en ancho y `216` en alto, por eso hasta pense que alguno de ellos estaba manejando otras unidades diferentes al pixel.